# WIX Installer can't install all it's MSI checkboxes

Tags: wix, burn

I created installer that should run 3 different MSIs , only "InstallExternalTools" is installed and responded on the GUI checker ( when I change value to "1" on this line :, the checkbox is set) . I am not sure why "InstallBinaryVersionsViewer" and "InstallDriverDebugTool" didn't install, even that msi is created, and not respond to default Value="1" (stay clear).

bundle.wxs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
  <Bundle Name="ToolsDebugPackage" Version="21.24.4.0" Manufacturer="Intel Corporation" UpgradeCode="208D0645-5CF9-4A99-B3DA-82F9639A57E3" IconSourceFile="..\Import\Intel_Image_Quality_Studio_WINDOWS.ico">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="..\Import\Docs\Intel_OBL_EGI_Internal_Use_License.rtf" LogoFile="..\Import\Intel_Image_Quality_Studio_WINDOWS_64px.ico" ThemeFile="..\Import\InstallerTheme\CustomizeBootstrapperToolsDebugPackage.xml" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <Chain>
      <!-- list of chained packages -->
      <PackageGroupRef Id="PreRequisites" />
      <PackageGroupRef Id="Applications" />
    </Chain>
      <!-- variable to capture checkbox value -->
      <Variable Name="InstallExternalTools" Type="numeric" Value="0" />
      <Variable Name="InstallBinaryVersionsViewer" Type="numeric" Value="0" />
      <Variable Name="InstallDriverDebugTool" Type="numeric" Value="0" />
  </Bundle>
  <Fragment>
    <Property Id="MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION" Value="1" />
    <!--checking for c++ Redistributable 2010 x64-->
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="redistributable_2010_64" Variable="redist2010Exists" Root="HKLM" Key="\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x64" Result="exists" Win64="yes" />
    <!--checking for c++ Redistributable 2012 x64-->
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="redistributable_2012_64" Variable="redist2012Exists" Root="HKLM" Key="\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\VC\" Result="exists" Win64="yes" />
    <!--checking for c++ Redistributable 2013 x64-->
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="redistributable_2013_64" Variable="redist2013Exists" Root="HKLM" Key="\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\VC\" Result="exists" Win64="yes" />
    <!--checking for c++ Redistributable 2019 x64-->
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="redistributable_2019_64" Variable="redist2019Exists" Root="HKLM" Key="\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0\Registration\" Result="exists" Win64="yes" />
    <PackageGroup Id="PreRequisites">
      <ExePackage Id="vcredist_2019_x64" Name="IQStudioInstaller\vcredist_x64_2015_2019.exe" Cache="no" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="no" InstallCommand="/q" SourceFile="..\BigImport\VCredist\vcredist_x64_2015_2019.exe" InstallCondition="(VersionNT &gt;= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 &gt;= v6.0)" DetectCondition="redist2019Exists" />
      <ExePackage Id="vcredist_2013_x64" Name="IQStudioInstaller\vcredist_x64_2013.exe" Cache="no" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="no" InstallCommand="/q" SourceFile="..\BigImport\VCredist\vcredist_x64_2013.exe" InstallCondition="(VersionNT &gt;= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 &gt;= v6.0)" DetectCondition="redist2013Exists" />
      <ExePackage Id="vcredist_2012_x64" Name="IQStudioInstaller\vcredist_x64_2012.exe" Cache="no" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="no" InstallCommand="/q" SourceFile="..\BigImport\VCredist\vcredist_x64_2012.exe" InstallCondition="(VersionNT &gt;= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 &gt;= v6.0)" DetectCondition="redist2012Exists" />
      <ExePackage Id="vcredist_2010_x64" Name="IQStudioInstaller\vcredist_x64_2010.exe" Cache="no" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="no" InstallCommand="/q" SourceFile="..\BigImport\VCredist\vcredist_x64_2010.exe" InstallCondition="(VersionNT &gt;= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 &gt;= v6.0)" DetectCondition="redist2010Exists" />
      <ExePackage Id="Netfx48Xxx" Cache="no" Name="IQStudioInstaller\ndp48-web.exe" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="no" InstallCommand="/q" SourceFile="..\BigImport\DotNet\4.8\ndp48-web.exe" DetectCondition="(Netfx4FullVersion=&quot;4.8.3925.0&quot;) AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion=&quot;4.8.3925.0&quot;))" InstallCondition="(VersionNT &gt;= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 &gt;= v6.0) AND (NOT (Netfx4FullVersion=&quot;4.8.3925.0&quot; OR Netfx4x64FullVersion=&quot;4.8.3925.0&quot;))" />
    </PackageGroup>
    <PackageGroup Id="Applications">
     <MsiPackage Id="ExternalTools" Name="ExternalToolsInstaller\ExternalToolsInstaller.msi" Cache="no" Compressed="no" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Vital="yes" SourceFile="$(var.externalToolsInstallerPath)\ExternalToolsInstaller.msi" SuppressSignatureVerification="yes" InstallCondition="InstallExternalTools=1" />
     <MsiPackage Id="DriverDebugTool" Name="WinDriverDebugToolInstaller\WinDriverDebugToolInstaller.msi" Cache="yes" Compressed="no" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Vital="yes" SourceFile="$(var.driverDebugToolInstallerPath)\WinDriverDebugToolInstaller.msi" SuppressSignatureVerification="yes" InstallCondition="InstallDriverDebugTool=1" />
     <MsiPackage Id="BinaryVersionsViewer" Name="BinaryVersionsViewerInstaller\BinaryVersionsViewerInstaller.msi" Cache="yes" Compressed="no" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Vital="yes" SourceFile="$(var.binaryVersionsViewerInstallerPath)\BinaryVersionsViewerInstaller.msi" SuppressSignatureVerification="yes" InstallCondition="InstallBinaryVersionsViewer=1" />
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

CustomizeBootstrapperToolsDebugPackage.xml:

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

#(loc.Caption)
Segoe UI
Segoe UI
Segoe UI
Segoe UI
Segoe UI

```
<Image X="11" Y="11" Width="64" Height="64" ImageFile="logo.png" Visible="yes"/>
<Text X="80" Y="11" Width="-11" Height="64" FontId="1" Visible="yes">#(loc.Title)</Text>

<Page Name="Install">
    <!--Richedit Name="EulaRichedit" X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="-90" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HexStyle="0x800000" /-->
    <!--Checkbox Name="EulaAcceptCheckbox" X="11" Y="-70" Width="246" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallAcceptCheckbox)</Checkbox-->
    <Checkbox Name="InstallExternalTools" X="11" Y="100" Width="246" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3">Install External Tools​​</Checkbox>
    <Checkbox Name="InstallBinaryVersionsViewer​" X="11" Y="115" Width="246" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3">Install Binary Versions Viewer</Checkbox>
    <Checkbox Name="InstallDriverDebugTool​​" X="11" Y="130" Width="246" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3">​Install Driver Debug Tool</Checkbox>
    <Button Name="OptionsButton" X="-171" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallOptionsButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="InstallButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallInstallButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="WelcomeCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallCloseButton)</Button>
</Page>
```

.
.
.

Log:

-We can see on the log that value change :'InstallDriverDebugTool​​' to value 1
but Condition 'InstallDriverDebugTool=1' evaluates to false. and didn't change to true as expected.

[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i001: Burn v3.11.2.4516, Windows v10.0 (Build 19042: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\estihaga\AppData\Local\Temp{1C263892-42C7-4EA1-953A-30BBCA08A881}.cr\ToolsDebugPackage.exe
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallExternalTools' to value '0'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallBinaryVersionsViewer' to value '0'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallDriverDebugTool' to value '0'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=D:\git\IQS\iqs-trunk\ia-tools-iqstudio\iqstudio\ToolsDebugPackage\bin\Release\ToolsDebugPackage.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=664 -burn.filehandle.self=672 -l 1.log'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'D:\git\IQS\iqs-trunk\ia-tools-iqstudio\iqstudio\ToolsDebugPackage\bin\Release\ToolsDebugPackage.exe'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'D:\git\IQS\iqs-trunk\ia-tools-iqstudio\iqstudio\ToolsDebugPackage\bin\Release'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'D:\git\IQS\iqs-trunk\ia-tools-iqstudio\iqstudio\ToolsDebugPackage\bin\Release\1.log'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'ToolsDebugPackage'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Intel Corporation'
[7620:5F08][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i000: Setting numeric variable 'WixStdBALanguageId' to value 1033
[7620:5F08][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '21.24.4.0'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i100: Detect begin, 7 packages
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]e000: Error 0x800700a1: Failed to open registry key. Key = '\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x64'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i000: RegistrySearchExists failed: ID '\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x64', HRESULT 0x800700a1
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]e000: Error 0x800700a1: Failed to open registry key. Key = '\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\VC'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i000: RegistrySearchExists failed: ID '\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\VC', HRESULT 0x800700a1
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]e000: Error 0x800700a1: Failed to open registry key. Key = '\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\VC'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i000: RegistrySearchExists failed: ID '\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\VC', HRESULT 0x800700a1
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]e000: Error 0x800700a1: Failed to open registry key. Key = '\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0\Registration'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i000: RegistrySearchExists failed: ID '\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0\Registration', HRESULT 0x800700a1
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i102: Detected related bundle: {1ace7db3-6701-4a56-a56d-1bfdd064fb68}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 21.24.4.0, operation: None
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i102: Detected related bundle: {382af873-8aec-4b88-9d0c-038bf8576777}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 21.24.4.0, operation: None
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i102: Detected related bundle: {d63691ef-8811-436b-8e1b-9ee921473d61}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 21.24.4.0, operation: None
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i052: Condition 'redist2019Exists' evaluates to false.
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i052: Condition 'redist2013Exists' evaluates to false.
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i052: Condition 'redist2012Exists' evaluates to false.
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i052: Condition 'redist2010Exists' evaluates to false.
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i052: Condition '(Netfx4FullVersion="4.8.3925.0") AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion="4.8.3925.0"))' evaluates to false.
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i101: Detected package: vcredist_2019_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i101: Detected package: vcredist_2013_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i101: Detected package: vcredist_2012_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i101: Detected package: vcredist_2010_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i101: Detected package: Netfx48Xxx, state: Absent, cached: None
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i101: Detected package: ExternalTools, state: Absent, cached: None
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i101: Detected package: DriverDebugTool, state: Absent, cached: None
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:17]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[7620:5F08][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i000: Setting numeric variable 'InstallExternalTools' to value 0
[7620:5F08][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i000: Setting numeric variable 'InstallBinaryVersionsViewer​' to value 0
[7620:5F08][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i000: Setting numeric variable **'InstallDriverDebugTool​​' to value 1**
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i200: Plan begin, 7 packages, action: Install
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i052: Condition '(VersionNT >= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 >= v6.0)' evaluates to true.
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: vcredist_2019_x64
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcredist_2019_x64' to value 'D:\git\IQS\iqs-trunk\ia-tools-iqstudio\iqstudio\ToolsDebugPackage\bin\Release\1_000_vcredist_2019_x64.log'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i052: Condition '(VersionNT >= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 >= v6.0)' evaluates to true.
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: vcredist_2013_x64
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcredist_2013_x64' to value 'D:\git\IQS\iqs-trunk\ia-tools-iqstudio\iqstudio\ToolsDebugPackage\bin\Release\1_001_vcredist_2013_x64.log'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i052: Condition '(VersionNT >= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 >= v6.0)' evaluates to true.
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: vcredist_2012_x64
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcredist_2012_x64' to value 'D:\git\IQS\iqs-trunk\ia-tools-iqstudio\iqstudio\ToolsDebugPackage\bin\Release\1_002_vcredist_2012_x64.log'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i052: Condition '(VersionNT >= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 >= v6.0)' evaluates to true.
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: vcredist_2010_x64
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcredist_2010_x64' to value 'D:\git\IQS\iqs-trunk\ia-tools-iqstudio\iqstudio\ToolsDebugPackage\bin\Release\1_003_vcredist_2010_x64.log'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i052: Condition '(VersionNT >= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 >= v6.0) AND (NOT (Netfx4FullVersion="4.8.3925.0" OR Netfx4x64FullVersion="4.8.3925.0"))' evaluates to true.
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Netfx48Xxx
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_Netfx48Xxx' to value 'D:\git\IQS\iqs-trunk\ia-tools-iqstudio\iqstudio\ToolsDebugPackage\bin\Release\1_004_Netfx48Xxx.log'
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i052: Condition 'InstallExternalTools=1' evaluates to false.
[7620:467C][2021-12-09T16:10:19]i052: **Condition 'InstallDriverDebugTool=1' evaluates to false.**

Comment: It should work, you probably misspelled something. The log (normally in %TEMP%) might be helpful to diagnose, otherwise you'd have to attach a debugger to see what's wrong.

Comment: @SeanHall which debugger? how can you debug this, can you share a link ?

Comment: If you create a public repo that has the source code to build a bundle that demonstrates this problem, I can look at it. Otherwise, download the wix311-debug.zip from https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/tag/wix3112rtm and use your favorite C++ debugger.